# Format a number format based on if condition in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell containing or Dollar.
If the cell value is Dollar then the next cell format should be in Dollar sign and if its percentage then its format should be percentage form. How can I do this using if condition in excel

[image]

As shown in the picture above if the cell takes percentage value it is 60% and if it takes Dollar value it is $60.

Comment: I'm sorry that I have to say your question is unclear. Can you bring it to a specific point and show what you have tried already? A screenshot could be helpful too. See [ask] if you have problems writing a good questions.

Comment: You can use Conditional Formatting on the Home tab

Answer (score 1):

I assume the cell to look at is `A1`

For the format changing cell:

- conditional formatting
- formula
- for currency:

  - `=LEFT(CELL("format",A1))="C"`
  - set the format for currency
- for percentage:

  - `=LEFT(CELL("format",A1))="P"`
  - set the format for percentage

---

However: if the other cell just uses a formula like `=A1` then it should change automatically (if the format is set to "general")